# A difficulty using rigidbodies

Tags: modeling, rigid-body-simulation

So basically i'm trying to do a ring attached to small chains...
However when i press Alt+A to animate, the "ring" detaches from the two bottom "chain"
Mass of "ring" = 30kg
Mass of each chain link = 4kg...
Scale are x= 2.376m
          y= 1.422m
      and z= 28.431
I learned the chain thingy from Blender Guru and he said something about the object being big...i'm not sure
Also the top 2 chains(left and right) have Active Rigidbodies but arent Dynamic, the rest is dynamic (even the ring)  Someone help pls...
[image]

here is my file:
[image]

Comment: it may be related to subdivisions, or bounding shape, solver settings... having the file would help us to help you better (if you wish so, use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then paste the provided link into your question or in comments)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3995" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3995/)
There you go @m.ardito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the file, it was easy: it's the unapplied scale for all chain rings (even the bigger one). They all have some scale like 1.846...

applying each (with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then "scale"), it becomes 1.0 and it behaves well...

[image]

Comment: Ty for the fix...i saw the scaling thing in another video...but completely forgot about it...xD ty once again

Comment: Related Link: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)